# Solve $x^3+x+57\equiv 0$ mod $125$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Solve $x^3+x+57\equiv 0$ mod $125$

So first I try to solve $x^3+x+2\equiv 0$ mod $5$

I have $f^\prime(x)=3x^2+1$

I found $f(4)$ to be the only solution.

And since $f^\prime(4)\equiv 4$ there is a unique solution mod $25$

So I then need to solve $f(4+t5)=f(4)+t\cdot 5\cdot f^\prime(4)\equiv 0$ mod $25$

$f(4)\equiv 20$ mod $25$ and $f^\prime(4)\equiv 24$ mod $25$

I'm not sure where to go from here,

I have that $20+t\cdot 5 \cdot 24\equiv 0$ mod $25$ and I want to solve for $t$

Comment: I get $f(4)\equiv 0\bmod 25$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote

> I have that $20+t\cdot 5 \cdot 24\equiv 0$ mod $25$ and I want to solve for $t$

So you have $25|20+t\cdot5\cdot24$.

That means $5|4+t\cdot24$ or $4+t\cdot24\equiv0\pmod5$.

Can you take it from there?

---

Addendum:

The answer above addresses only where OP got stuck.  It does not address other parts of the whole problem.  In fact, as seen in comments and discussion there, $f(4)$ is actually $\equiv0$, not $20,\mod 25,$ in contrast to what the question states, so applying the above would lead to the wrong answer; rather, the approach indicated above should be applied with the correct congruence in order to obtain the correct answer.

Comment: Since $4+t\cdot 24\equiv 0$ mod $5$, then $4(1+t\cdot 6)\equiv 0 $ mod $5$. Then $1+t\cdot 6\equiv 0$ mod $5$ then $t\equiv -1\equiv 4$ mod $5$

Comment: That is correct; and note that $6\equiv1\pmod5$

Comment: So I get that $f(4)\equiv 0$ mod $5$ lifts to $f(24)\equiv 0$ mod $25$. And now I just repeat this process  to $125$? Also its true that you you can't 'skip' powers of $5$ right? i.e I can't go straight from a solution mod $5$ to a solution mod $125$?

Comment: You should lift one power at a time, and the solution to $x^3+x+57\equiv0\mod25$ is $x\equiv4$

Comment: I'm not sure what I did wrong then. I get that $1+(4)\cdot 6\equiv 0$ mod $5$. So $4+(4)\cdot 5$ should be the solution shouldn't it?

Comment: $(4+5k)^3+(4+5k)+57\equiv0\mod25\implies 4^3+3\cdot4^2\cdot5k+4+5k+57\equiv0\mod25$ 
 $\implies(3\cdot4^2+1)5k\equiv0\mod25\implies(3\cdot4^2+1)k\equiv0\mod5\implies k\equiv0\mod5, $ so the solution is $4$, as can be verified:  $4^3+4+57\equiv0\mod25$

Comment: I see that it works but I don't see what I did wrong.

Comment: Isn't $f'(x)=3x^2+1$ and $f(4)\equiv0\mod25$?

Comment: I think I realized my mistake. When taking $f(4)$ mod $25$ I used the polynomial reduced mod $5$. I should have gotten that $f(4)\equiv 0$ mod $25$

Comment: @J.W.T It would be a good idea to update your answer to warn that is is using the OP's incorrect calculation (else it may confuse many readers).

Comment: @BillDubuque:  I was thinking that too.  Will do

Answer (score 2):

$x^3+x+57\equiv 0\pmod {125}\Rightarrow x^3+x-68\equiv 0\pmod {125}\Rightarrow (x-4)(x^2+4x+17)\equiv 0\pmod {125}.$

How did I get $x-4?$ I simply used the fact that $x-4$ is a factor of the polynomial $x^3+x-68.$

Since the quadratic $x^2+4x+17$ has no solutions $\pmod {125},$ the only solution is $x=4\pmod {125}.$ You didn't need to start with $\pmod 5.$

Comment: You don't say how you found the factor $\,x-4\,$ of the cubic. That's like pulling the root $\,x=4\,$ out of a hat - like magic. But magic is not math. Nor do you prove the claim that the quadratic has no solutions.

Comment: oh for that I just tried plugging in factors of 68

Comment: But $68$ is a unit mod $125$ so it has *many* factors mod $125$, viz. every integer coprime to $5$. So that won't save any work vs. brute force trying all possible values in general. Either you got lucky (or used Alpha).

Comment: Why 68?  Why not factors of 182 or 1057?

Comment: @OscarLanzi 68 is easy to work with.

Comment: I suppose you _could_ argue that 68 is $n^3+n$ for an easily spotted $n$.

Comment: @Simon Why is 68 "easier to work with" than 57?  No, I'm not implying that you need to use (Hensel) lifting. Rather I'm trying to help you improve your answer so readers can understand what you did. Currently it is pulled out of a hat with no clue as to its genesis.

Comment: @BillDubuque I edited my answer.